# BufferedWriter java problems

Tags: java, file-io

i try to print something to file. so i create a array of BufferedWriters (there is reason why array) .  and when i run the program, nothing happend. the files are empty.

here is my code:

```
BW = new BufferedWriter[8];
for(int  i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    BW[i] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(TablePath + i + ".txt"));
    BW[i].write("asdfgh");

}
```

this code create the txt files. but not write then anything.

what is the problem?

Comment: Did you closed/flushed writers?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line inside loop

```
BW[i].Close();
```

It will work fine after that, you have to flush and close the BW.

Answer (score 1):

Close the BufferedWriters. Doing so will also flush their content so you don't have to call flush() as well.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
    BW[i].close();
}
```